# Best way to keep the values of two variables in sync in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, coffeescript

So I have two variables.

One is `ammo` and the other is `ammoAvailable`.

When the user left-clicks, `ammo` is reduced by 1, but can never go past 0.

When the user right-clicks, `ammoAvailable` is reduced by 50 (or less if not available) and `ammo` is increased by the same amount.

What's the most elegant way to handle this variable relationship in Javascript so that no extra ammo is ever created and neither variables ever go below 0?

Example:

```
@ammo = 0
@ammoAvailable = 500

userClick = =>
  if @ammoAvailable >= 50
    @ammo += 50
    @ammoAvailable -= 50
  else
    @ammo += @ammoAvailable
    @ammoAvailable = 0
```

How can I do this more eloquently, and shorter?

Comment: @Barmar I tried making two variables and having one decrease while the other increases. I'm perfectly able to solve the problem I just want to know how to do it best.

Comment: @Barmar Added my way of doing it to the question. Can you improve?

Comment: Best is in the eye of the beholder, which is why questions like this are generally considered inapproproate for SO.

Comment: @Barmar I will accept anything that is shorter than my way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take:

"When the user left-clicks, `ammo` is reduced by 1, but can never go past 0."

```
leftClick = =>
  @ammo-- if @ammo
```

"When the user right-clicks, `ammoAvailable` is reduced by 50 (or less if not available) and `ammo` is increased by the same amount."

```
rightClick = =>
  reloadAmmo = Math.min @ammoAvailable, 50
  @ammo += reloadAmmo
  @availableAmmo -= reloadAmmo
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I'm glad it materialized despite how anal the SO community is. If anyone has any suggestions on a title edit so that people with a similar problem can find this answer I would accept their edit immediately.

Comment: Also did not know about Math.min, that's nice to know about!

Comment: @JacksonGariety, well, it's quite a specific question. With its current title i don't think many people who have a similar problem would find it. Maybe "how to keep the values of two variables in sync" (coming up with good titles is hard hehe). Or maybe something like "how to avoid unnecessary branches to keep two variables in sync"... because i think that's the main problem in the little code snippet of the question: unnecessary branches. It's a very common problem, and one that can make complexity grow out of control very quickly :)